Exporting Excel Sheet as PDF files using a UserForm throws a error when using arrays
I created a UserForm for exporting some Excel WSheets to PDF, the required Sheets to be exported are selected using CheckBox in the form; some PDF documents may include more sections or Sheets (aligned to the right) if those are selected. Please focus on the left side of the Form.

So for example, if the "CALCULATION REPORT" is selected it will export the Sheets with the names : "MCP", "MCG", "MCG1", "MCG2", "MC 1", "MC 2", "MC 3", "MC 4", "MC 5", "MC 6".
In addition, if the left checkboxes are selected other sheets will be added to the document (only one document is generated by each left-aligned checkbox) according to the following:
if "CFE MDOC SEISM" checkbox is selected then the following Excel sheets will be added to the file to export : ("MCG CFE 1", "MC7", "MC8").
and for  "CFE MDOC WIND" -----> "MCG CFE V 1", "MC9" and so on as you can see in the code.
The problem is that I'm getting an error at line :

21 at "ConcatenateArray" Type mismatch : an array or user-defined type was expected.

I'm not really used to VBA but I need to complete this.
The code is as follows:
Sub ExportarPDF_SELECTIVO()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arraySD() As String
    Dim nbre As String
    Dim ruta As String
    Dim frm As Object ' UserForm (ajusta el tipo de objeto según tu UserForm)
    Dim ctrl As Object ' Control (checkbox)

    ' Supongamos que los checkboxes están en un UserForm llamado "UserForm2"
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm2").Designer

    ' Veriy if checkbox "CALCULATION" is checked
    If frm.Controls("CALCULATION").Value = True Then
        ' Agrega las hojas principales al array
        arraySD = Array("MCP", "MCG", "MCG1", "MCG2", "MC 1", "MC 2", "MC 3", "MC 4", "MC 5", "MC 6")
        
        ' Verify ifa checkbox "CALC_CFE_SEI" is checked
        If frm.Controls("CALC_CFE_SEI").Value = True Then
            ' Add additional sheets to array
            arraySD = ConcatenateArrays(arraySD, Array("MCG CFE 1", "MC7", "MC8"))
        End If
        
        ' Verify if checkbox "CALC_CFE_WIND" is selected
        If frm.Controls("CALC_CFE_WIND").Value = True Then
            ' Add additional sheets to array
            arraySD = ConcatenateArrays(arraySD, Array("MCG CFE V 1", "MC9"))
        End If
    End If

    ' Verify if there are sheets to export
    If UBound(arraySD) >= 0 Then
        ' Verify export address
        ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        If Dir(ruta, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MsgBox "URL NOT FOUND.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Loop to export
        For i = LBound(arraySD) To UBound(arraySD)
            Set ws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = Worksheets(arraySD(i))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                nbre = [TÍTULO] & " - TECHNICAL SUMMARY"
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=ruta & nbre & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
            Else
                MsgBox "La hoja '" & arraySD(i) & "' no existe.", vbExclamation
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "No sheets selected.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

Function ConcatenateArrays(arr1() As String, arr2() As String) As String()
    Dim combined() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    ReDim combined(UBound(arr1) + UBound(arr2) + 1)
    
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        combined(i) = arr1(i)
    Next i
    
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        combined(i + j + 1) = arr2(j)
    Next j
    
    ConcatenateArrays = combined
End Function

Thank you for your help
I tried different options like make it one by one but it does not work either
Dim i As Integer
    Let i = 1
    Dim arraySD(0 To 1) As String
    
    arraySD(i - 1) = "DS"
    
    If PS_CALC_RESULT.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "DS 2"
    End If
    If PS_NOZZ_STRC.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "DS 3"
    End If
    If PS_SCHEDULE.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "DS 4"
    End If
    If PS_SKETCH.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "DS 5"
    End If
    If PS_MH.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "MHS"
    End If
    If PS_JACKING.Value = True Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
        arraySD(i - 1) = "JTS"
    End If
    If PS_BOM.Value = True Then
    i = i + 2
    ReDim Preserve arraySD(0 To i)
    arraySD(i - 2) = "MAT"
    arraySD(i - 1) = "MAT 2"
    End If


Which line has the error?

Array() returns a Variant of type "array" - that's not the same as a variable of type String()
Instead of
Dim arraySD() As String
you can use
Dim arraySD 'Implicit variant
Likewise adjust your ConcatenateArrays function to accept variants.

Your problem is that VBA doesn't consider a single element array to be an array. but rather just a single element of the native Datatype. What you need to do is verify whether you are passing in a single string or an array.  Try using this as a check and if it returns false, handle your Redim statement to use "1" instead of the UBound statemnt :
   Private Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function

